# Sufficient condition for a Group map to be a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and consider a map $\gamma: G \rightarrow G$. Say we know that $\forall a,b \in G$ we have that $\gamma(aba^{-1})=\gamma(a)\gamma(b)\gamma(a)^{-1}$

Does this imply that $\gamma(ab)=\gamma(a)\gamma(b)$? Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider $\gamma:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gamma(x) = x + 2$. Then $\gamma(a+b-a) = \gamma(b)$ and also $\gamma(a) + \gamma(b) - \gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$, so we have the required condition, but this is not a homomorphism. Is there a reason why you’re looking for something more complicated than just $\gamma(ab) = \gamma(a) \gamma(b)$?

Comment: Yes, there indeed is. I'm trying to understand the motivation of the adjoint representation of a lie group. A lie group homomorphism $\gamma$ respect the action of a group $G$ on itself by conjugation, and on page 106 of Fultons representation theory he gives a third characterization of a lie group homomorphism as respecting the adjoint action of a group $G$ on its tangent space. I though since this was a characterization the implication was supposed to go both ways

Comment: OOh, theres a note at the bottom of the page explaining the implication is only one way. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Just to expand on @OsamaGhani's comment a bit: if $G$ is any abelian group and $\gamma:G \to G$ is **any function at all**, then $\gamma$ satisfies this condition.